# Cannot create directory named uc.micro on W7/10

Tags: windows, locked-files

On Windows 7/10, I get Access Denied when trying to create a directory named `uc.micro`, or anything else with `micro` after a dot. What would account for this?

Windows explorer attempt to create folder "aaaa.micro"

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Not reproducible. Where and how are you trying to create the directory?

Comment: Can you create other folders in that directory (just to rule out a permissions issue)

Comment: So this is an issue on 2 operating systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a virus named `.micro` in your windows machine and [here](http://www.removemalwarevirus.com/how-to-get-rid-of-micro-file-extension-ransomware-removal-guide) is the guide about the same.

As I tried to create a directory with `uc.micro` and `cu.micro` **(using GUI and via DOS prompt)** and worked fine for me. Try to use the [link](http://www.removemalwarevirus.com/how-to-get-rid-of-micro-file-extension-ransomware-removal-guide) to remove the virus and create a directory.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Well it turns out not that I have the virus, but that my anti-virus prevents the creation of directories ending in `.micro`.